# Connection timeout on 8081 port in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https

I am configuring https in Tomcat 7. I have generated a key store file and added a tag in the server.xml. I am using 8081 as the default port. When I am accessing https://servername.abc:8443/, it is working, but http://servername.abc:8081/ is not.

Getting error "The connection has timed out. The server at servername is taking too long to respond.".

```
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="9999999" 
           maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" 
           enableLookups="false" acceptCount="100"
           disableUploadTimeout="true"
           redirectPort="8443" />


<Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" 
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="SSLv3" 
ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"/>
```